# Xcode: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, xcode

I made a func counter() and have seconds -= 1 and a label.text in it. I tried to make a if marioButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) [my button for the app] { seconds += 0 } but get the Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred. Any help would be appreicated. I can give more info if needed.

```
 func counter()
{
    seconds -= 1
    label.text = String(seconds) + ""

  *if marioButtonPressed(<#T##sender: AnyObject##AnyObject#>) {seconds += }*
    if (seconds == 0)
    {
        timer.invalidate()

        gameOver.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.gameOver.center = CGPoint (x:  self.gameOver.center.x + 500, y: self.gameOver.center.y)})

}
}
```

*Code which I have an error with.*

Also, how do I make it so if the timer hits 0 my button stops working?

Comment: Edit your question to include the definition of `marioButtonPressed`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `sender: AnyObject` is still a "placeholder". You can see this in the by the blue background / bubble in your original screenshot.

Select the placeholder and replace it with the object that you're expecting to pass to that function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete the function, the placeholder you have is only for showing that you have to complete such space. try something like `marioButtonPressed(sender:self)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you defined `marioButtonPressed` like this:

```
func marioButtonPressed<T: AnyObject>(_ sender: T) -> Bool {
    return true // or whatever
}
```

And then you probably tried to call it like this:

```
func counter() {
    // ...
    if marioButtonPressed(nil) { seconds += 1 }
    // ...
}
```

The problem with this call is that `nil` by itself doesn't have a full type; it means `Optional<Something>.none` and Swift deduces the `Something` from the context in which `nil` appears. There's not enough information here to deduce a `Something`.

You could provide the compiler with an explicit type. For the definition I wrote above, you'd have to do this:

```
    if marioButtonPressed(nil as AnyObject? as AnyObject) { seconds += 1 }
```

It's a weird double-`as` because `marioButtonPressed` takes a `T`, not a `T?`. Since `nil as AnyObject?` means `Optional<AnyObject>.none`, you have to then wrap that in a non-optional `AnyObject`.

Anyway, the better fix is almost certainly to change `marioButtonPressed` not to take an argument at all. A `sender` argument is usually used in an `@IBAction` method, but an `@IBAction` method cannot be generic and should not return `Bool`. So `marioButtonPressed` can't be an `@IBAction`, so it probably shouldn't have a `sender` argument. It should just be defined like this:

```
func marioButtonPressed() -> Bool {
    return true // or whatever
}
```

And it should be called like this:

```
    if marioButtonPressed() { seconds += 1 }
```

Or you could even make it a property like this:

```
var marioButtonPressed: Bool {
    return true // or whatever
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
    if marioButtonPressed { seconds += 1 }
```